# Why igraph spinglass giving me 'Cannot work with unconnected graph'?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, nodes, igraph, vertices

I'm experimenting with different community detection algorithms and was able to get some results for all the community detection algorithms expect spinglass. I'm using exactly the same graph but I get an error.

Code

```
g = Graph.TupleList(tupleMapping)
cl = g.community_spinglass()
```

Error

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 1265, in community_spinglass
membership = GraphBase.community_spinglass(self, *args, **kwds)
igraph._igraph.InternalError: Error at clustertool.cpp:286: Cannot work with unconnected graph, Invalid value
```

I do have edges and vertices and the same graph works with all the other community detection algorithms in igraph (Leading eigenvector, GN, InfoMap, Label propagation, Multi-level, Walktrap) just not spinglass.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of the spinglass clustering algorithm that is included in igraph works on connected graphs only. You have to decompose your graph to its connected components, run the clustering on each of the connected components, and then merge the membership vectors of the clusterings manually.

Answer (score 1):

As already said,

> The implementation of the spinglass clustering algorithm that is
>   included in igraph works on connected graphs only. You have to
>   decompose your graph to its connected components, run the clustering
>   on each of the connected components, and then merge the membership
>   vectors of the clusterings manually.

you can decompose your main graph using the `clusters` method of *iGraph* like in the example bellow:

```
    clusters    = g.clusters()
    giant       = clusters.giant() ## using the biggest component as an example, you can use the others here.
    communities = giant.community_spinglass()
```